# Ignore certain nodes when sorting XML with Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML. Roughly, there is the Root node. Then a level below that you have various nodes, some of the which have the tag "System". Within each "System" node there are various other nodes, some of which are called "Extents". The finally within "Extents" there are various nodes, one of which will be "LineSize" which a "Value" attribute set to a number.

I'm basically trying to sort each "System" node so that all the "Extents" are ordered by "LineSize". I want to ignore all other nodes within "System" and just sort the "Extents" in order. Ideally leaving the other nodes where they are (they always either come before all the "Extents" or after).

this is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

my_tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = my_tree.getroot()

for node in root:
    if node.tag == "System":
        for child_node in node:

            child_node[:] = sorted(child_node, key=lambda segment_node: int(segment_node.find("LineSize").attrib["Value"]), reverse=True)

my_tree.write('test_ordered.xml')
```

The issue right now is that it won't find "LineSize" for elements other than "Extents", so will throw an error.

XML is similar to this. The only change once I run working code would be that extents with id = 1 would come after extents with id = 2 as I'd be ordering descending (both still under the system with name = aa.

The graphics node would just stay in the same place, or at least, wouldn't be part of the sorting.

```
<root>
 <system name = "aa">
  <graphics>
  </graphics>
  <extents id = "1" name = "aa">
   <LineSize Value = "10" />
  </extents>
  <extents id = "2" name = "aa">
   <LineSize Value = "40" />
  </extents>
 </system>
 <system name = "bb">
  <extents id = "3" name = "bb">
   <LineSize Value = "90" />
  </extents>
  <extents id = "4" name = "bb">
   <LineSize Value = "20" />
  </extents>
  <random1>
  </random1>
  </system>
 <random>
 </random>
</root>
```

Comment: Ive added an example

Comment: @mzjn Do you think this is posible? I'm basically just trying to sort based on the value of a child node

Comment: That was not valid XML (there was a missing `"`). I've corrected it, but in general it's best to ensure that any code or data you include in your question is syntactically correct (because syntax issues distract from our ability to look at the real problem).

Comment: Additionally, the sample document doesn't match your code. It does not contain any `<System>` elements (note capitalization).

Comment: Thanks. The XML was just quickly put together as I can't share the actual XML with the real confidential data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

my_tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = my_tree.getroot()

for node in root:
    if node.tag == "system":
        child_nodes = sorted(
            node,
            key=lambda node: int(node.find("LineSize").get("Value", 0))
            if node.tag == "extents"
            else 0,
        )
        for child_node in reversed(child_nodes):
            node.remove(child_node)
            node.insert(0, child_node)

my_tree.write("test_ordered.xml")
```

We get the list of child nodes of each `<system>` element, then sort the list by `extents.LineSize`, placing elements that are not `<extents>` at the top of the list. For each child node, we first remove it from whatever position it previously occupied and then re-insert it.

Run on your sample data, this produces:

```
<root>
  <system name="aa">
    <graphics></graphics>
    <extents id="1" name="aa">
      <LineSize Value="10" />
    </extents>
    <extents id="2" name="aa">
      <LineSize Value="40" />
    </extents>
  </system>
  <system name="bb">
    <random1></random1>
    <extents id="4" name="bb">
      <LineSize Value="20" />
    </extents>
    <extents id="3" name="bb">
      <LineSize Value="90" />
    </extents>
  </system>
  <random></random>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried updating this so it would  order the opposite way (highest first). However, seems to result in some issues. One of the extents ends up outside the system node.

Comment: Although this may be an issue with VS Code with it's formatting. It looks like it might be working when I had reverse = True

Comment: If you want highest first, just use `for child node in child_nodes` instead of `for child node in reversed(child_nodes)` (that is in fact what I tested first, but I assumed you wanted lowest first so I added the `reversed()` call). This will place non-`<extents>` nodes at the bottom instead of hte top, but if that's an issue you can use a large value instead of `0` as the default value in the `sorted()` call.